# Prevent model creation when building associations with Waterline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have two model, ModelA and ModelB, with a one-to-many association : ModelA owns a lot of ModelB.

```
// ModelA
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        model_b: {
            collection: ModelB
        }
    }
};
```

---

```
// ModelB
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        model_a: {
            model: ModelA,
            required: true
        }
    }
};
```

When I create a new ModelB, I have to assign it to an *existing* ModelA. However, when I give a ModelA object as a parameter to the ModelB's create function, it doesn't bother if the ModelA exists or not : it tries to create a new one.

I tried to fix this with a beforeValidate function which replace the given ModelA object by its id if it exists and throws an error if it doesn't. This function isn't even called...

Have someone already faced this kind of issue ? How should I handle this ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: `However, when I give a ModelA object as a parameter to the ModelB's create function, it doesn't bother if the ModelA exists or not : it tries to create a new one.`

It's true that you means is `it doesn't bother if the ModelA exists or not` or `if the ModelB exists or not`?

Comment: ModelA. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Don't hesitate to ask if you need more details.

Comment: Could you paste the complete code in the question please ? Maybe we could see why `beforeValidate` is not called.

Comment: If you would like an additional resource, here is a chat room for sails.js, node.js, and waterline questions. https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails